# Log base 2 en excel, error en la formula

Tags: excel, excel-2013

tengo esta formula

=12/24*(-7/12LOG(7/12;2)-5/12LOG(5/12;2))+12/24*(-8/12LOG(8/12;2)-4/12LOG(4/12;2))

pero los parentesis del log estan en rojo y al momento de dar enter, el sistema me dice 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se si escribi mal la funcion, pero lo que quiero escribir es esto
[image: mi hoja]

o como se hace realmente? gracias :)

Comment: Antes de cada `LOG` de debes colocar el simbolo **`*`** para indicar la multiplicacion. Luego de eso si te sigue mostrando una advertencia, entonces en la funcion `LOG` separa los argumentos por **`,`** (coma) y no por punto y coma. Esto ultimo solo es en algunas versiones de excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba `=12/24*(-7/12*LOG(7/12;2)-(5/12)*LOG(5/12;2))+12/24*(-8/12*LOG(8/12;2)-(4/12*LOG(4/12;2)))`

Comment: Muchas gracias :)